# Point on the edge of a triangle

Tags: limits, geometric-construction

[image]

$$\mathrm{I}=\int_{0}^{h_1}\int_{x_L}^{x_U}\Lambda(r^\prime)\frac{e^{-jkR}}{4\pi R}dx dy$$
Here,
$$x_L = \hat{n}\cdot\left(\hat{h_1}\times \overrightarrow{ \ell_2} \right) \left(1-\xi\right)$$
where,
$$\xi\,\mathrm{is}\,1\,\mathrm{or}\,0\,\mathrm{for}\,y=0\,\mathrm{or}\,h_1$$

How is $\hat{n}\cdot\left(\hat{h_1}\times\overrightarrow{\ell_2}\right)$ multipled with $\left(1-\xi\right)$ will be the lower limit $x_L$ of the integral $\mathrm{I}$?

Comment: $\hat n \cdot \left(\hat h_1 \times \vec{\ell_2}\right)$ is a number, not a vector, as is $1 - \xi$. Thus $x_L$ and $x_U$ are also numbers.  Presumably, the points where they are shown would be $x_L\vec \ell_2$ and $x_U\vec \ell_3$.

Comment: Yes. They are not vectors. My question is how does it falls on the edges?

Comment: Numbers do not fall *anywhere* in space. They do not "fall on the edges". They are NUMBERS, not points. Not vectors. As I already said, what you see is not $x_U$ and $x_L$, but $x_U\vec\ell_3$ and $x_L\vec\ell_2$. And they fall on the edges because $\vec\ell_2$ and $\vec\ell_3$ are the edges, so any multiples of them will be points on the edges.

Comment: The $x_L$ and $x_U$ are the lower and upper limits of the integral and the other limits being the zero and the height of the triangle.

Comment: I understood $\left(\hat{h_1}\times\overrightarrow{\ell_1}\right)$ is a vector which is parallel to $\hat{n}$ and it the dot product with it results in a scalar. But I do not understand how this is part of the limits.

Comment: I don't either because you have said *nothing* about any integcal or any limits. I cannot look inside your head.

Comment: Sorry Sir. It's part of the algorithm for Singularity cancellation (Duffy method of Singularity cancellation). I will update the question in detail soon...

Comment: Updated the question now. Hope it is more clear on what I want to find out.